# $\lim_{ t\rightarrow -8} \left(t^2 − 64\right) /\left (2t^2 + 17t + 8\right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How do I solve the quotient function above? I know the numerator is the difference of squares but how do you factor the bottom part?

Comment: Since the bottom equals 0 when $t=-8$, you know that $t+8$ will be a factor of the bottom.

Comment: I'm still lost.

Comment: Try writing $2t^2+17t+8=(2t+\_ )(t+8)$, and finding what goes in the blank (or use the hint below).

Comment: Do you know the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula_and_its_derivation)?

Answer (score 2):

It holds
$$2t^2+17t+8 = 2t^2+16t+t+8 = 2t(t+8)+t+8 = (2t+1)(t+8)$$

Thus you have

$$\frac{t^2-64}{2t^2+17t+8} = \frac{(t-8)(t+8)}{(2t+1)(t+8)}$$

Hence
$$\lim_{t\to -8} \frac{t^2-64}{2t^2+17t+8} = \lim_{t\to -8} \frac{(t-8)(t+8)}{(2t+1)(t+8)} = \lim_{t\to -8} \frac{t-8}{2t+1}= \dots$$

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking the denominator as $2t^2+16t+t+8$. Note that $2t^2+17t+8$ = $2t^2+16t+t+8$= $2t(t+8)+(t+8)$ = $(2t+1)(t+8)$. The numerator is $(t+8)(t-8)$. Cancel $t+8$ from top and bottom, and then take the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Find the roots of both num and den to have:

$$L = \lim_{t\to-8} \frac{(t-8)(t+8)}{2(t+8)(t+1/2)},$$

cancel out the $(t+8)$ terms and perform the limit.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $t=-8$ makes the denominator zero, then a factor of the denominator has to be $t-(-8)=t+8$.  If you don't know that (and you didn't indicate that you did):

If the denominator factors, it has the form $(2t + a)(t + b)$.  $ab=8$ and the coefficient of $t$ ($17$) is positive, so $a$ and $b$ are positive.  The pair $(a,b)$ must be $(1,8), (2,4), (4,2)$, or $(8,1)$.  Use trial-and-error until you find the pair that works.